# How to stop Windows from prompting user for Certificate A3 PIN/Password?

Tags: c#, windows, security, certificate, smartcard

Windows operational system keeps asking the user to input PIN/Password when the Certificate is an A3 Smartcard/eToken.

But in my application (C# Windows Forms) I already input the PIN programmatically when the application process starts and access the Certificate.

I suspect its a Windows Security setting because this problem occurs just in some developers/clients machines, in others don't.

**Is there any Windows Security setting that makes it stop prompting the user for PIN?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions tend to be answered better if they contain at least one sentence that ends in a question mark. ;) iow: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the tip, I think it's better now 